# Deploying routed angular 5 application on tomcat 7 for routing work correctly

Tags: tomcat7, angular2-routing, angular5

For using tomcat 7 to be deployment server for routed angular application the server needs some settings to be fallback on index.html for routing to be work from the browser's url box. [refer to angular.io](https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml)

What configuration do I need in tomcat 7 in order to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

In case you still need it:
You need to add the rewrite Valve to your tomcat server.xml file `(~/conf/server.xml)`, like this:

`<Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
   <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.rewrite.RewriteValve" />
...
</Host>`

Also, you need to write rewrite rule in rewrite.config:
Create rewrite.config file in `~/conf/Catalina/localhost/` with the following content:

`RewriteCond %{REQUEST_PATH} !-f
RewriteRule ^/appName/(.*) /appName/index.html`

And change the baseHref for your app to serve files and route correct for deep links. this is an example:

`ng build --prod --baseHref=http://hostname:port/appName/`

This is working for me in tomcat 8.xx and 9.x.x